# Differences between fa() and factanal() functions in R

Tags: r, statistics, components, factors

I'm performing an exploratory factor analysis on my dataset, composed of 23 variables (which are questions asked to people). I got 1777 observations for these variables and I would like to investigate the latent factors that can explain these variables. Therefore, I used first the function `fa()` and then I tried with the function `factanal()` which doesn't give the same results for which I have difficulties to interpret.

Does anyone can explain me the differences between `fa()` and `factanal()` functions please?

Comment: `fa` is not a base R function, while `factanal` is. That, at least is a starting point. To see details about `factanal`, type `?factanal` into the console.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, after analysing the help in R, I found the main differences which are:

factanal performs a maximum-likelihood factor analysis on a covariance matrix or a data matrix while fa() function is a more general function in the sense that it proposes different fit methods such as Ordinary least square regressions (OLR). fa() also permits to draw a Factor Analysis diagram in order to retrieve visually which factors explain which variables with the different loadings showed.

In conclusion, I would say that fa() permits more flexibility than factanal()

Answer (score 0):

`factanal` uses varimax rotation as the default and maximum likelihood estimation. Just set the right parameters and the results are the same for `fa`:

```
model <- fa(..., fm = "ml", rotate = "varimax")
```

For a comprehensive example that shows that the results are the same, see:

https://johannestitz.com/post/2023-03-08-how-to-get-the-same-results-with-factanal-and-psych-fa-in-factor-analysis-with-r/