Why do the factor loadings from R's fa() and factanal() functions differ when using the promax rotation?
I tried to use factanal() from base R and fa() from the psych package to perform a factor analysis on data from a questionnaire with same response scale for each question.
Why do I obtain different factor loadings from the two functions even with having Maximum likelihood set for both methods when using the "promax" rotation? This is a reproducible example:
# Load the psych package for 
# data analysis and visualization 
library(psych) 
library(GPArotation)

# Load the mtcars dataset 
data(mtcars) 

# Perform factor analysis on the mtcars dataset 
factanal <- factanal(mtcars, factors=3, rotation="promax") 
fa <- fa(mtcars, nfactors = 3, fm="ml", rotate="promax")

# Print the results 
head(round(factanal$loadings, 2))

     Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
mpg     0.54    0.16   -0.43
cyl    -0.53   -0.58    0.08
disp   -0.65   -0.32    0.19
hp     -0.11   -0.48    0.47
drat    0.83    0.12    0.10
wt     -0.71    0.18    0.54

head(round(fa$loadings, 2))

       ML2   ML1   ML3
mpg   0.52  0.17 -0.43
cyl  -0.51 -0.59  0.08
disp -0.63 -0.33  0.19
hp   -0.09 -0.49  0.48
drat  0.83  0.13  0.10
wt   -0.70  0.16  0.54


In R documentation, they recommend to use "oblique.Scores=TRUE", but that does not change the factor loadings:
fa2 <- fa(mtcars, nfactors = 3, fm="ml", rotate="promax", oblique.scores=T, scores="tenBerge")
head(round(fa2$loadings, 2))

       ML2   ML1   ML3
mpg   0.52  0.17 -0.43
cyl  -0.51 -0.59  0.08
disp -0.63 -0.33  0.19
hp   -0.09 -0.49  0.48
drat  0.83  0.13  0.10
wt   -0.70  0.16  0.54

While the question has already been asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50573764/differences-between-fa-and-factanal-functions-in-r#:~:text=factanal%20performs%20a%20maximum%2Dlikelihood,least%20square%20regressions%20(OLR).
the answer is not completely true, as in the article they link to they say "same results" but it is same results only when we use "varimax" rotation.

"[...] and how to know which of both methods could be the best [...]" -- voted to close. This question is more about other stuff than programming.

@Friede knowing why there is the difference could lead then to know which one is the best, it's only secondary. And i don't know if i miss some options that could explain those differences, it's programming.

fa <- fa(mtcars, nfactors = 3, fm="ml", rotate="Promax")

This question was not  " ... seeking recommendations for software libraries, tutorials, tools, books, or other off-site resources." , it was asking why there were differences between the results of two functions .. the promax rotations.

@Friede ; I think you focused too much on one (off-topic) sentence and not on the general tone  of the question or on the request for help on differing results. Never the less I have removed the offending sentence from the questio.n Reproducible example was also provided.

You can get the same rotation as stats::promax, used by factanal, by using Promax (note the upper case P). The help page of ?Promax explains:

Promax is a very direct adaptation of the stats::promax function. The addition is that it will return the interfactor correlations as well as the loadings and rotation matrix.

I have not looked in the docs to see what promax, from the psych package, is doing (I'm sure it will be in there as they are very good) but a quick look at the source code for fa reveals that it returns a rotation of the normalised loadings:
    Promax =   {pro <- Promax(loadings,...)  #Promax without Kaiser normalization
                loadings <- pro$loadings
                 Phi <- pro$Phi 
                 rot.mat <- pro$rotmat},
     promax =   {#pro <- stats::promax(loadings,...)   #from stats
                pro <- kaiser(loadings,rotate="Promax",...)   #calling promax will now do the Kaiser normalization before doing Promax rotation

Code showing the equivalence:
library(psych)
data(mtcars)
m1 <- factanal(mtcars, factors=3, rotation="promax")
m2 <- fa(mtcars, nfactors = 3, fm="ml", rotate="Promax")
loadings(m2)[] - loadings(m1)[]
#                ML2           ML1           ML3
# mpg  -1.705875e-06  1.473799e-06 -3.059439e-07
# cyl   1.594591e-07 -8.884557e-07 -1.818443e-07
# disp  8.168498e-07  4.712348e-07  2.310251e-06
# hp    6.522325e-07 -1.931424e-06 -1.722668e-06
# drat  8.599102e-07  1.509280e-06  8.609054e-07
# wt    2.121750e-06  8.515195e-07  3.925057e-06
# qsec  1.092731e-06  1.119313e-06  2.633606e-06
# vs    4.688156e-07 -8.692953e-07 -6.737374e-07
# am   -1.884347e-06  1.230842e-06 -1.514240e-06
# gear -1.691097e-06 -2.111156e-06 -5.330317e-06
# carb  1.288899e-06 -2.468629e-06 -2.641025e-06


Thank you for the answer! I did not notice that there were 2 different promax with lower and upper case first letter. Next time i will be careful to not "ask" if one is better, thanks again for your time.

While it could be that e.g. the loadings are not normalized, it could also be an MLE issue since normalization typically can change loadings pretty notably provided there's enough variance yet the loadings are quite close to each other. MLE is not deterministic. Accordingly, the differences could just be the optimizer moving into nearby but different parts of the likelihood and stopping before they both converged at the exact same solution (even default settings for the optimizer might differ). I'd suspect this is likely given how small the differences are.

@socialscientist; in this case I think the psych documentation and code / author comments in the code, would seem to indicate that the  Promax and  promax rotations are calculated, within the psych package, using different methods ... so some difference could be expected beyond optimiser settings. By setting the rotation argument correctly the loadings then correspond to that from the stats package - without touching optimisr settings
